# Search and replace variable values using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am at a loss as to how to achieve the search and replace outcome shown below. Can some kind soul please guide me?

Input.txt (input file with variables to be replaced):

```
parameter EIW=3.4
parameter WQA=6.6 + 43.5 + 55.8
parameter IID=4.64
...
parameter KDO=2.322 * 393.3
```

NewVariableValues.txt (values of the parameters in source file are to be replaced by new values found in this file):

```
parameter ACE=newparam1
parameter WQA=newparam2
parameter KDO=newparam3
...
```

Output.txt:

```
parameter EIW=3.4
parameter WQA=newparam2 + 43.5 + 55.8
parameter IID=4.64
...
parameter KDO=newparam3 * 393.3
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether gobbling up the first value after the `=` is intentional, but assuming it is, here's without much error checking:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $replacements =  shift or die "missing arg";
open my $fh, '<', $replacements or die "can't open $replacements: $!";
# Slurp file and build a hash of intended replacements
my %rep = map { /^parameter ([^=]+)=(\S+)/ } <$fh>;
close $fh;
while(<STDIN>) {
    # Replace text after the = with a hash lookup if possible
    s/^parameter ([^=]+)=(\S+)/sprintf "parameter %s=%s", $1, $rep{$1}||$2/e;
    print;
}
```

You pass your replacements file as an argument and provide the original input on STDIN. Of course one should usually check for format errors, empty lines and such in the files; stuff like that will just throw an error or warning now.

Comment: You should say how to run this program. It is a little strange to accept the replacements file as a command-line parameter, and the input file on STDIN

Comment: It's the common Unix filter paradigm: input on STDIN, output on STDOUT, extra inputs on the command line. It works with inputs that are in a file already using input redirection but on top of that it also works in a pipe without any `/dev/fd/...` tricks.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simply done using a expression substitution, with the `/e` modifier

This program first opens file `NewVariableValues.txt` and builds a hash `%new_values` from it that relates each new parameter name to its value. Then file `Input.txt` is read, and the `value` in all `NAME=value` constructions are replaced by the corresponding value from the hash

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.14.1;
use autodie;

my %new_values;
{
    open my $fh, '<', 'NewVariableValues.txt';
    while ( <$fh> ) {
        $new_values{$1} = $2 if /([^\s=]+)=(.+)/;
    }
}

{
    open my $fh, '<', 'Input.txt';
    while ( <$fh> ) {
        s<([^\s=]+)=\K(\S+)><$new_values{$1} // $2>e;
        print;
    }
}
```

#### output

```
parameter EIW=3.4
parameter WQA=newparam2 + 43.5 + 55.8
parameter IID=4.64
...
parameter KDO=newparam3 * 393.3
```

Answer (score -1):

Example for line : `parameter WQA=6.6 + 43.5 + 55.8`

You can try something like:
`line =~ s/(parameter WQA= ?)([0-9.]+)/\1$newparam1/`

(assuming you know how to get newparam1 from the file)

Comment: Please, don't use back reference in the replacement part. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Backreferences